# Add all values in a CSV column in Python

Tags: python, csv

These seems like something very simple, but search as I might I just can't get past it.

I have a CSV file like this:

```
Day,Event,Value
1,"Rent",500
7,"Wage Payments",1000
```

I wish to add up all of the numbers in the 'value' column. So far, my code is this:

```
cr = csv.reader(open("file.csv","rb"))

for row in cr:    
    print row

#print sum(Value)
```

How could I go about summing that value?

Thank you.

Comment: `sum(int(row[2]) for row in csv.reader(open("file.csv","rb")) if row[2].isdigit())`

Comment: `sum(map(int, zip(*csv.reader(open("file.csv","rb")))[2][1:]))`

Comment: `sum(int(row['Value']) for row in csv.DictReader(open("file.csv","rb")))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Considering the first line of `csv` file is `'Day,Event,Value'`, you can use a `generator expression` with `sum()`

```
>>> cr = csv.reader(open("file.csv","rb"))
>>> cr.next()
>>> print sum(int(x[2]) for x in cr)
1500
```

Comment: Hint for any novices, remove the ```cr.next()``` line if you don't want to skip the first row in the csv file.  That's just there to skip the header row.

Answer (score 3):

```
cr = csv.reader(open("file.csv","rb"))
cr.next() # to skip the header 

total = 0
for row in cr:  
   total += int(row[2])
   # possibly do other things with data/rows 

print total
```

There are more terse ways (e.g., [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), or generator expressions) to do this, but this provides the basic idea and also lets you do other things with each line as needed (as pointed out by @MarkRansom too)

Comment: If there's a need to do work (such as print) for every row in addition to generating the sum, this is the best way. Don't forget to cast to `int` though.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks - I'll update the answer to include the cast. Do you know if CVS also pulls in the header?

Comment: Yes it does, it doesn't know or assume that there's a header on the file.

Comment: @Levon `row[2]` must be converted to `int()`

Comment: @Levon in python 2.7 the `cr[1:]` throws an error --> `TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary  hmm .. I guess I'll go with cr.next() .. I was trying not to clutter up this code .. looks almost baroque compared to your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a garbage value and read in the first 2 values and "trash" them then when reading in the 3rd value add it to your sum. Don't forget that initially you need to ignore the first 3 values of the file since it will pick up the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Given that 'value' is in column 2, you can perform the following simple for loop:

```
value_sum=0
for row in cr:
    value_sum += row[2]
```

Or, you can use a comprehension, if you understand it:

```
value_sum = sum([row[2] for row in cr])
```

Comment: No need to make that list, you can just do `sum(row[2] for row in cr)`(although it looks like you will also need a cast to int)